# Where to host a React SPA with Spring Boot Backend nowatodays

Tags: docker, heroku, web-hosting

I have more organizational question.

I want to a little React Single Page Application that works on a Spring Boot Backend Mircroservice (Maybe as a docker image) with a MongoDB and is adressable on my on internet address…. e. G.  MyLittleReactSpringApp.com.

**What provider could you recommend?** Is Heroku something that is able to do all at once? Host a SPA and a backend behind the same domain adress?

Are there better alternatives?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use Heroku for such projects a lot. It is quite easy to manage it, easy to perform deployments and it is relatively cheap.

For spring boot application you have two options that I would consider - Docker and direct deployment:

1. Deployment via Docker means publishing to registry and then deploying app from there. Convenient if you have some additional features to be present on your deployment machine. For instance, some specific version of Java. You can include them into Docker image.
2. Direct deployment means you push the code to Heroku Git repo, build it on the Heroku server and run it there(check Heroku doc for it, but it is pretty straightworward).

I prefer later option for its simplicity. And of course, I don`t have any special requirements for my Spring Boot app.

React app is very simple case. It is also deployed via Heroku Git.
First you need to create app on the Heroku via Heroku Cli:
heroku create appname

where appname is obviusly name of your app

And then from the folder of your app:
npm install
git add --all
git commit -m "first commit"
git push heroku master

That is it. Your application becomes available by address:
https://appname.herokuapp.com/

Of course, this is just a brief description how all works, better to check documentation which, by the way, is quite good for Heroku. Would be glad to answer any more specific questions.